# Low Voltage Photosensor

Tags: sensor, light, phototransistor, photodiode

I'm looking for a photosensor/photo IC part (combination of photodiode, linear amplifier, Schmitt trigger and output transistor) that can be powered with 3.3V. Fairchild QSE256/257/258/259 is almost exactly what I need, except that it requires 4-16 volts supply voltage and not working very stable at 3.3. I know that there is a number of parts usually used in the infrared receivers, but they contain demodulator (from 38KHz) which I don't need. Anyone here knows a good alternative to Fairchild part?

Answer (score 1):

In [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36086/does-this-photodiode-circuit-work) is explained that a photodiode doesn't need a voltage across it to generate a photocurrent:

[image]

Do you need all the functions integrated into one IC? You have plenty of options if you would pick a common photodiode plus a comparator. Comparators exist for DLV (Damn Low Voltages™) these days; Digikey lists more than a thousand which will happily run at 3.3 V or less. The [MCP6546](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21714G.pdf) is the cheapest I found:

- 1.6 V to 5.5 V power supply
- open-drain output
- internal hysteresis

If the 30 mA current sink is not sufficient you can use the [MCP6541](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21696H.pdf), which has a push-pull output, from which you can drive an external transistor. This would also allow you to switch much higher voltages, as well as set your own hysteresis levels. In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/33474/2064) I explain how to calculate the required resistances.